# Differences between using pointer to the class member and the structure member

Tags: c++, class, pointers, structure

I am new to c++.I was told the structures and the classes are almost the same.The main differece is classes in c++ are by default private while structures are public.

I have two different codes where we use pointers to structure members and classe members.

```
struct Simple { int a; };
int main() {
Simple so, *sp = &so;
sp->a;
so.a;
}
```

We use pointers to struct members in the above way.

Why do we have to use the pointers to class members int he following way?

```
class X {
public:
  int a;
  void f(int b) {
    cout << "The value of b is "<< b << endl;
  }
};

int main() {

  // declare pointer to data member
  int X::*ptiptr = &X::a;
  int X::*ptiptr1 = &X::a;

  // create an object of class type X
  X xobject,xobject1;

  // initialize data member
  xobject.*ptiptr = 10;
  xobject->*ptiptr1 = 11;

}
```

Why are we first declaring a pointer to the class data member? Why can't we do it like we have done for structures?

Please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference, other than default access of members and base classes (public vs. private) between `class` and `struct`.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges and complaining that they aren't the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing two very different things here.

The first is creating a normal *object pointer* to one particular object. This refers to that object, and can be used to access any of its members.

The second creates a *pointer-to-member*, which is very different to an object pointer. It refers to a class member and not a particular object, and can be applied to any object to access that member.

In either case, it's irrelevant whether the class is defined using the `class` or `struct` keyword. That only affects whether members default to being private or public.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct S {
    int a;
};

class C {
public:
    int a;
};
```

The very same what you did with the `struct`:

```
S so, *sp = &so;
sp->a = 3;
so.a = 3;
```

you are also able to do with `class`:

```
C co, *cp = &co;
cp->a = 3;
co.a = 3;
```

And regarding the pointer to member: Such a pointer requires an instance of that `struct` / `class` in order to be used to access this member. Non-static members are specific for objects, thus the pointer alone is useless unless you have an object, member of which can be accessed:

```
S so;
int S::* memberPtr = &S::a;
so.*memberPtr = 3;
```